# Eclipse Preferences do not contain an Ivy section after installing IvyDE

Tags: eclipse-luna, ivyde

I installed 4 components from the update site http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/ivyde/updatesite mentioned on [Apache IvyDE™ > Download](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/download.cgi) including a restart of Eclipse:

- Apache Ivy
- Apache Ivy Ant Tasks
- Apache IvyDE
- Apache IvyDE Resolve Visualizer

They are displayed in *Help → Installation Details → Installed Software*.

There is an *Ant* section but no *Ivy* section in *Window → Preferences*.

Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Welp, I have the exactly same issue for installing IvyDE here in MyEclipse 10. I thought there is a manual installation available? Endless times of uninstall then reinstall through Eclipse Marketplace doesn't really help...

Comment: @si_the_nibba I'm working (again) with Maven in the meantime and I'm happy, so this doesn't bother me any longer. If you can switch from Ant/Ivy as fast as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found (and I didn't *find* it, in fact, I tried it because I didn't find any other solution) was to:

- abandon the Eclipse workspace (losing all the settings and plugins I've installed so far, of course)
- create a new one from scratch
- install the IvyDe plugin as first step before doing anything else

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's an old thread, not really sure of anyone cares, but if you do, and you're using Ant, this might do the trick:

After installing IvyDE, right-click your project folder within package explorer, scroll down to Configuration option in the big popup menu, and select Add Ivy Dependency Management from next popup menu.

Now, if you right click your project folder again, you should be able to see new menu item called Ivy (just above Team option).
You should also be able to see the new item (Ivy) when you right-click Project -> Properties.

Hope you find this helpful.
Props to roseindiatutorials@yt for providing the solution.